# Audience error while using firebase analytics on ios

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I built an iOS app that uses [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) to track user properties and events.

When enabling the firebase logging, I get the following error:

> 5.1.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS006009] Audience definition is invalid. Audience will not be saved. Audience, error: , Error Domain=com.google.gmp.measurement.ErrorDomain
>   Code=9 "Audience filter count out of range"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Audience filter count out of range}

This error seems not to be associated with any particular line of code, but a general warning that there is a problem with the way I use GAforF.

As this seems to be a common warning, was anyone able to fix this in their apps?

Comment: I noticed the same warning in my app, there is no mention of this in the firebase documentation anywhere. Was anyone able to fix it?

Comment: pod update guys. You need 
Firebase 5.4.1 FirebaseAnalytics 5.0.1 FirebaseCore 5.0.6 FirebaseInstanceID 3.1.1 FirebaseMessaging 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a problem with the Back-end sending an empty Audience filters to the SDK. You will see this message sometimes when you first install the app or after a while, the SDK tries to fetch the Audience again. You can safely ignore the message as it will eventually go away when the Back-end fixes the issue. The SDK is working as intended.

Comment: You got any sources for this information? Reluctant to trust random dude on the internet.

Comment: I'm an engineer in Firebase Analytics iOS team so I hope it makes my information more credible. You can see my comment on the official Firebase Github issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1624#issuecomment-410282857

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @FlowNivettop, updating Firebase Analytics frameworks solved this issue for me.  I don't use Cocoapods, so had to manually download the package and update the linked Frameworks.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

After updating I no longer receive this logged error...hope this helps!